# pass a few lines of a single file to equivalent number of map in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I have a file say at path hduser/path/filename. Now I want to pass first K lines of this file each to K maps. Simply setting

```
FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path("hduser/path/filename"));
```

passes the all the lines (all N lines each to N maps). But I want to limit this to K < N. That is I want to process only a few lines of a file in mapreduce and not the complete file(say like word count of a selection of text in the file)

Answer (score 0):

You could:

Use NLineInputFormat (which splits N lines of input as one split)
http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/NLineInputFormat.html

But in this case rest of the splits will be processed too....but each split is N Lines.

OR

You could override the run method of the Mapper to control when you want to exit the run method (and therefore the Mapper).